# why datetime object sometimes return date, and sometimes return date and time?

Tags: python, datetime

I got a wired problem.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start_date = '2019-05-01'
end_date = '2020-04-30'

start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(start_date)

new_start_date = (datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d') - timedelta(days=360)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(new_start_date)
```

The return is

```
2019-05-01 00:00:00
2019-05-06
```

It looks like, the first "start_date" contains date and time, and the second "new_start_date" only has date. Why?
How can I make change to let the first "start_date" return only date, no time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strptime` returns a `datetime` object. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

> classmethod datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
>
> > Return a datetime corresponding to date_string, parsed according to format.

Where as `strftime` returns a string specified by your formatting string. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

> date.strftime(format)
>
> > Return a string representing the date, controlled by an explicit format string. Format codes referring to hours, minutes or seconds will see 0 values. For a complete list of formatting directives, see strftime() and strptime() Behavior.

In your example;

```
datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d") #2019-05-01 00:00:00
```

However if you were to use `strftime` to format this, it would proceed to remove the time;

```
datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) #2019-05-01
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_start_date` is not a `date`, it is a `string`. You can remove `strftime` to get the `datetime` object.